# Why can't my beam DoFn see my global imports?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a beam pipeline that uses a custom DoFn and references imports (like `time`) inside of its body.

Full code is [here](https://github.com/whylabs/dataflow-templates/blob/so-question-imports/src/ai/whylabs/templates/profile_query_template.py#L71), the idea is below.

```py
import time

class MyView(beam.DoFn):
    @beam.DoFn.yields_elements
    def process_batch(self, batch: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> Iterator[Tuple[str, MyType]]:
        start_time = time.perf_counter() # fails
        # rest of code
```

I have a strange issue where my pipeline will fail if I run it from Github CI, but not if I run it directly on my machine. The most recent failure was

```
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

It just fails at whichever is the first import that it hits in the DoFn. I can move the imports into the DoFn body but I shouldn't need to do that, especially since it works when I run it locally. I'm running it locally and in CI with the (same command)[https://github.com/whylabs/dataflow-templates/blob/so-question-imports/Makefile#L31-L49] as well, so something about the runtime environment is causing the issue. That pipeline already has `pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True` also, which I thought was supposed to address this problem by pickling the entire main.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was a python version mismatch. I'm using 3.8 for this project and, despite specifying 3.8 in CI using (abatilo/actions-poetry)[https://github.com/abatilo/actions-poetry], I was getting 3.9. I assume the issue there was that I had the poetry step before the setup-python step, but whenever I put it after the setup-python step I got an error.

I switched to (Gr1N/setup-poetry)[https://github.com/Gr1N/setup-poetry] instead and everything worked as expected. The python version mismatch probably just lead to some strange pickling issues.